# json.Marshal returns a byte slice with an unexpected capcacity

Tags: go

So I have a situation wherein I need to return `""` as a byte slice from the `MarshalJSON` interface assuming certain conditions are satisfied.

One fact I observed during writing the unit tests for this interface is that the byte slice returned while calling the `json.Marshal` on the type, has the **capacity set as 8**(unexpected) and the **length set as 2** (expected).

Q: Can someone help me understand the reason for this behaviour? Shouldn't the slice capacities be identical since in both cases I am essentially using `` []byte(`""`) ``

The code to reproduce is provided below. You can also checkout the playground URL https://go.dev/play/p/SvgmOVgoNNb

```golang
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct{}

func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`""`), nil
}

func main() {
    s1 := []byte(`""`)
    f := Foo{}
    s2, _ := json.Marshal(f)
    fmt.Printf("Len: %d, cap: %d\n", len(s1), cap(s1))
    fmt.Printf("Len %d, cap: %d\n", len(s2), cap(s2))
}
```

Comment: The capacity of string to byte slices is not defined and the compiler can do whatever it seems fit; and it did. Nothing really to see here. Your expectations of "cap should be 2" is just unwarranted and should be "cap must be at least 2 (and probably shouldn't be much larger)". Which it is.

Comment: You've outsmarted yourself, really ;-) As Volker said, nothing in the `encoding/json` states anything about the capacities of the byte slices the functions implemented by that package return. (Actually, off the top of my mind I can only recall just a single facet of the standard library which _almost_ explicitly talks about byte slice capacities: `strconv.Append*` functions.) So, just use `bytes.Equal` in your test (and look at its documentation: it does not mention capacity either!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json.Marshal copies bytes returned from MarshalJSON and other built-in encoders into a buffer along with any other JSON Syntax and then returns a copy of the buffer's content.
There is no reason to expect json.Marshal to return the result of MarshalJSON unchanged, because in the general case there is not just a single MarshalJSON call.

We can take a look at [json.Marshal's implementation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/encoding/json/encode.go;l=158) to see that in your case it effectively returns the result of `append([]byte(nil), '"', '"')`.

`append` grows (and in this case creates from scratch) slices according to some heuristics that aim to minimize amortized memory allocations. You must not make assumptions about these heuristics because they are not part of the language specification and can change (and they did in the past).